# How to insert into a temporary table?

Tags: tempdb, sybase-asa

I'm working with Sybase Central using Adaptive Server Anywhere 9 and I want some examples of how to use tempDB.

How can I insert some records in to a temporary table?

I tried:

```
select * into TempDB.dba.#testing from testTable
```

But I got the following error:

> Syntax error near '.' on line 1

Comment: why is there a "#" ? also , it should be tempdb

Comment: i changed it into select * into tempdb.dba.testing from afdeling
but still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two sets of temp tables and you have mixed them up

1) Session related there are access as #table ie

```
select * into #testing from testTable
```

This lasts as long as your connection

2) tables in tempdb. These persist until the server gets rebooted.

```
select * into TempDB.testing from testTable
```

See sybase docs for more info [ASE](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sag1/html/sag1/sag145.htm)

Comment: select * into TempDB.testing from testTable works ! :) but the table testing doesnt exsist it says. I thought that it would create it automatically .

Comment: I think I made a typo try TempDB..testing

Comment: unfortunately,i get the following error again: Syntax error near '.' on line 1

Comment: Never mind mark, insert into TempDB.testing(select * from table) also works, thk u very much for the help !!

Comment: Ah insert into TempDB.testing(select * from table) works if the table already exists select into works if it does not exist